# Problem with Google Now in Tab 2

Tags: google-now, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I have a Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 which I have updated to the official jellybean provided by Samsung, it is supposed to have Google Now but I cant see the cards on opening the the app. Can anyone help me out by pointing out the way in which I can see the cards.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest Google Search?

Comment: And, which flavor of Jelly Bean? 4.1 or 4.2?

Comment: Yes I have updated the google search, and the version of jelly bean is 4.1

Comment: Please update your question. Comments are, by their nature, impermanent.

Comment: Also, if I recall, Google Now is not worldwide. What country are you in?

Answer (score 0):

Press home button and then slide to the search icon. You should be able to see "show more cards" button. If not then slide down to the very bottom of the screen, you will see three dots in the bottom-right corner. Click this, open Settings dialog and then click on Google Now tab. You will have the option to turn it on then. If it's not appearing check also TOP RIGHT corner of the screen for a switch available.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that there simply are no cards to display.  If you don't have a wireless connection on, for instance, it can't fetch data to populate cards for viewing.

Available cards also depend on several other factors such as whether the GPS is on, whether you allow Google to track you/your data, and what country you live in (most Now cards are US-centric; living in Canada, the only ones that ever come up for me are weather and "time to travel" Navigation cards)